# Sitecore.Kernel 10.2- no attributes

Tags: upgrade

In `Sitecore.Kernel 9.1` there were attributes, for example: `Sitecore.NotNullAttribute` I don't see them in version `10.2` of this library. Does anyone know if they've been moved, or is there a replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sitecore 10 they are in `Sitecore.Annotations.dll`, e.g.

```
Sitecore.Annotations.NotNullAttribute
```